# jQuery unwrap() multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to clean up html before saving to database. Here is my structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="inner">
            <p>Text goes here...</p>
          </div>
          <a class="handle"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="inner">
            <p>Text goes here...</p>
          </div>
          <a class="handle"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="inner">
            <p>Text goes here...</p>
          </div>
          <a class="handle"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm after is this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <p>Text goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <p>Text goes here...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <p>Text goes here...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
        $("#container").children('.row').each(function() {
            $(this).children('.cell').each(function() {
                var cell = this;
                $(cell).find('.inner').children().unwrap();
            });
        });
```

With my code, I'm only able to remove .inner div, and nothing else.
Can I remove both .inner, and .wrapper in one shot, or do I need to create another each loop?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `unwrap` is what you are looking for since you want to remove the `anchor` element also.

You can reset the contents of the `cell` element instead like

```js
$('#container .cell').html(function(){
  return $(this).find('div.inner').contents();
});

console.log($('#container').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="inner">
            <p>Text goes here...</p>
          </div>
          <a class="handle"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="inner">
            <p>Text goes here...</p>
          </div>
          <a class="handle"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="inner">
            <p>Text goes here...</p>
            more
          </div>
          <a class="handle"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the thing is I will have more elements not just 'p' within inner div, that was just the idea what I'm after.

Comment: @Alko so what kind of elements do you want to keep, can you give a better markup example

Comment: Any  type of html could be within .inner div

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively easy, just use raw HTML:

```js
function clean(wrapper) {
  console.log('cleaned');
  $("#container .row .cell").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).find('.inner').html());
  });
}
```

```css
body *:not(button) {
  padding: 10px
}
.container {
  background: #223344;
}
.row {
  background: #443322;
}
.cell {
  background: red;
}
.wrapper {
  background: blue;
}
.inner {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="clean()">Clean</button>
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inner">
          <p>Text goes here...</p>
        </div>
        <a class="handle">link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inner">
          <p>Text goes here...</p>
        </div>
        <a class="handle">link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inner">
          <p>Text goes here...</p>
        </div>
        <a class="handle">link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```